# Four line syllogism in LaTeX

Tags: logic

Is it possible to have three premises in a syllog in LaTeX? The `syllogism` package outputs the following

[image]

by writing this

```
\syllog{Test}
{Test}
{Test}
{Test}
```

I had no luck by reading the package documentation ([here](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/syllogism/syllogism.pdf)).

**Edit**: the desired output would be in the form:

[image]

Comment: What's an example of a syllogism with three premises?

Answer (score 1):

Which particular feature do you need from the `syllogism` package that couldn't be achieved by other (simpler) means? E.g., with a definition like

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand\syllogism[3][]{%
  \begin{center}
  \def\tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\tmp\empty\else(#1)\quad\fi
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    #2\\\hline#3\quad$\therefore$
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
}
```

in your preamble you can write something like

```
\syllogism[S1]{
  All Greek men are mortal.\\
  Socrates is a man.\\
  Socrates is Greek.
}{
  Socrates is mortal.
}
```

(with arbitrarily many premises) to obtain

[image]

For complex proofs, there are several packages, see e.g. [www.actual.world/latex](http://www.actual.world/latex/).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand\syllogism[3][]{%
  \begin{center}
  \def\tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\tmp\empty\else(#1)\quad\fi
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    #2\\\hline#3\quad$\therefore$
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
}
\begin{document}
\syllogism[S1]{
  All Greek men are mortal.\\
  Socrates is a man.\\
  Socrates is Greek.
}{
  Socrates is mortal.
}
\end{document}
```