# Adjust spacing in tabular environnement for syllogistic-like structures

Tags: tables, spacing

Following [Four line syllogism in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577862/four-line-syllogism-in-latex), I'd just like to increase the space between the last premise and the conclusion regarding to the bar.

```
\documentclass{scrarticle}

\newcommand\syllogism[3][]{%
  \begin{center}
  \def\tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\tmp\empty\else(#1)\quad\fi
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    #2\\\hline#3\quad 
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\syllogism[S3]{
  Le soleil s'est levé tous les matins jusqu'à présent.
}{
  Le soleil se lèvera demain.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few approaches to increase space in `tabular`s.

The simplest way is to increase `arraystretch` by a factor greater than `1`. Add the following macro before `\begin{center}`

```
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.35}
```

Stretching tables this way is not symmetric, which is more visible the higher is the factor.

You could also add invisible bars in front of each cell

```latex
\newcommand\syllogism[3][]{%
  \def\tmp{#1}
  \begin{center}
    \ifx\tmp\empty\else\hspace*{0pt}\llap{(#1)\quad}\fi
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
      \rule[-6pt]{0pt}{6pt}#2\\\hline
      \rule[7pt]{0pt}{6pt}#3
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}}
```

Try to work out the numbers in `\rule[rise]{width}{height}`. `raise` means to either move up or move down a rule depending on if the length is positive or negative. `width` of `0pt` creates an invisible rule.

EDIT. There are a couple of alternatives. You could add [cellspace](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cellspace) package and utilise its custom column-type `Sx` (`x` being either `l`, `c`, or `r`), which adds extra spaces above and below cells defined by `S`. Another package [nicematrix](https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix) has a similar functionality (see section 2 of the [documentation](https://mirror.apps.cam.ac.uk/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf))

Below is the full example. Note I have enclosed a number in `\llap{...}`, which pulls the number to the left without affecting the table and keeping it at the centre. IMO, this is visually more readable.

```latex
\documentclass{scrarticle}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newcommand\syllogism[3][]{%
  \def\tmp{#1}
  \begin{center}
    \ifx\tmp\empty\else\hspace*{0pt}\llap{(#1)\quad}\fi
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
      \rule[-6pt]{0pt}{6pt}#2\\\hline
      \rule[7pt]{0pt}{6pt}#3
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}}


\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]

\syllogism[S3]{%
  Le soleil s'est levé tous les matins depuis jusqu'à présent.
}{%
  Le soleil se lèvera demain.
}

\kant[1][2]

\syllogism{%
  Le soleil s'est levé tous les matins depuis jusqu'à présent.
}{%
  Le soleil se lèvera demain.
}

\kant[1][3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT 2

```latex
%%% Requires etoolbox package for \notblank{}{}
\NewDocumentCommand\syllogism{O{}O{3pt}mm}{%
  % #1 - label (optional)
  % #2 - spacing aorund the rule (optional, default 3pt)
  % #3 - content above the rule
  % #4 - content below the rule
  \begin{center}
    \IfValueT{#1}{\notblank{#1}{\hspace*{0pt}\llap{(#1)\quad}}{}}%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{\notblank{#2}{\dimen0=#2}{\dimen0=3pt}}{\dimen0=3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
      #3\\\noalign{\vspace{\dimen0}\hrule height 0.4pt\vspace{\dimen0}}#4
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}}
```

Now, the macro accepts 2 optional and 2 mandatory arguments and the second argument controls spacing around the rule.

Here's the demo

```latex
\documentclass{scrarticle}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\NewDocumentCommand\syllogism{O{}O{3pt}mm}{%
  \begin{center}
    \IfValueT{#1}{\notblank{#1}{\hspace*{0pt}\llap{(#1)\quad}}{}}%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{\notblank{#2}{\dimen0=#2}{\dimen0=3pt}}{\dimen0=3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
      #3\\\noalign{\vspace{\dimen0}\hrule height 0.4pt\vspace{\dimen0}}#4
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}}


\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]

\syllogism{% All arguments are default
  Le soleil s'est levé tous les matins depuis jusqu'à présent.\\
  Test 1\\
  Test 2
}{%
  Le soleil se lèvera demain.
}

\kant[1][2]

\syllogism[S3][6pt]{% Explicit label and specing 
  Le soleil s'est levé tous les matins depuis jusqu'à présent.\\
  Test 1\\
  Test 2
}{%
  Le soleil se lèvera demain.
}

\kant[1][3]

\syllogism[][12pt]{% No label and explicit spacing
  Le soleil s'est levé tous les matins depuis jusqu'à présent.\\
  Test 1\\
  Test 2\\
  Test 3\\
  Test 4
}{%
  Le soleil se lèvera demain.
}

\kant[1][4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution works fine with one premiss. I should have precised that I'd like to use this template for an infinite number of premisses. Is there a way to stipulate that the last premiss before the conclusion is the one to be modified with the specific ruling values? Or does this require a case-by-case addition within the argument? (same goes with arraystretch).

Comment: @jfk Have a look at my answer below `Edit 2`. I have changed the macro, which accepts an additional optional argument that controls spacing around the rule. Also, you can change the rule width. The default value is `0.4pt`.